# postgres 11.6 - Creating array of JSON Objects from JSON array

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have the following schema here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5c73a/1

I want to create a query where the results will be something like this:

```
id    |      tags    
_________________________________
1.    |  [{"id": "id", "title": "first"}, {"id": "id", "title": "second"},{"id": "id", "title": "third"}]
2     |  [{"id": "id", "title": "fourth"}, {"id": "id", "title": "fifth"},{"id": "id", "title": "sixth"}]
```

The idea is to build an array with an object for each line of the array, the important is the title variable

Comment: What's the purpose of repeating `"id": "id"` in every array element of the output? Or should that `'"id": 1` for the first row and `"id": 2` for the second?

Comment: The id will be repeated due to the schema that will receive this, since the schema receives this and other data, since the original data don't have ids they will be repeated but not used when handling the data further on.

Comment: But what's the purpose of having a key named `"id"` with the string value `"id"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unnest the array and then aggregate it back:

```
select t.id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', 'id', 'title', tg.title))
from things t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(tags) as tg(title)
group by t.id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bac8d2d53dfb0720ad09c8a1c70c8a88)